# subscribe to arduino message

Tags: ros, arduino, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

My arduino send geometry twist message about robot path on `/robotpath` topic, when i type `rostopic echo /robotpath` i see the values `(x,y,theta)` change, but my subscribe node on ros read just the first value when it runs and hold it. I need to build a path controller for my project.

Thanks a lot.

my code is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

class robocont
{
public:
  robocont();

private:
  void roboCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& robotpath);
  ros::NodeHandle nh_controller;
  ros::Subscriber robo_sub; 
};

 robocont::robocont()
{ 
  robo_sub = nh_controller.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/robotpath", 1000, &robocont::roboCallback, this);
}

void robocont::roboCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& robotpath)
{
  while(nh_controller.ok()){  
  ROS_INFO("Robot Postion:(%.2f, %.2f. %.2f)" ,robotpath->linear.x, robotpath->linear.y, robotpath->angular.z);
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "odometry_Control");
  robocont odometry_Control;
  ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219762/subscribe-to-arduino-message/) by [hana](https://answers.ros.org/users/24813/hana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you write `ros::spin()` in your code? See [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) for more information. Most probably, that is the problem. Otherwise, can you post your ros subscriber code?

**Update:**

This is the correct code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

class robocont
{
public:
  robocont();

private:
  void roboCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& robotpath);
  ros::NodeHandle nh_controller;
  ros::Subscriber robo_sub; 
};

 robocont::robocont()
{ 
  robo_sub = nh_controller.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/robotpath", 1000, &robocont::roboCallback, this);
}

void robocont::roboCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& robotpath)
{
  ROS_INFO("Robot Postion:(%.2f, %.2f. %.2f)" ,robotpath->linear.x, robotpath->linear.y, robotpath->angular.z);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "odometry_Control");
  robocont odometry_Control;
  ros::spin();
}
```

In your callback function, you had `while(nh_controller.ok()){  }` because of which it was stuck in the loop and kept on printing the same value.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hana](https://answers.ros.org/users/24813/hana/) on 2015-10-24**:
Thank you, this is my code, i don't know where the problem

**Comment by [hana](https://answers.ros.org/users/24813/hana/) on 2015-10-24**:
Thank u very much .... the problem has been solved

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-10-24**:
Then, can you accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others also

**Comment by [hana](https://answers.ros.org/users/24813/hana/) on 2015-10-24**:
I need to ask if the Callback function can read two topic at the same time (refernce path and real path)

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-10-25**:
Ask a new question